# How to use "being"?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english, sentence

> I'm tired of being settling everything.

Is my sentence grammatically correct? I'm confused in particular about how to use "being" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need "being" because you are using that verb already in "I'm".

The correct sentence would be 
"I'm tired of settling everything."

If you felt like using 'being' here because you wanted to add some context to how often you are settling things, and how annoyed you are, perhaps 
"I'm tired of *always* settling everything" would accomplish the nuance you're aiming for.

Comment: As a way to still use "being" (if you really must): "I'm tired of being the one who has to settle everything". But that's just more verbose than your answer without adding anything, really.